# Return sum using aggregate function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have two tables.

Table1 has following data

```
Id1  Name   Comments
--------------------
 1   abc     hgdhg
 2   xyz     mnoph  
 3   ysdfr   jkljk
 4   asdf    iiuoo
 5   pqrs    liuoo
```

Table2 has following data

```
Id2   Id1   count      date
-------------------------------
 1     1      18     11/16/2005
 2     1      1     11/15/2005
 3     1      4     11/25/2005
 4     2      4     11/22/2005
 5     3      8     11/05/2005
 6     3      3     11/30/2005
 7     4      2     11/29/2005
 8     3      0     11/04/2005
 9     2      5     11/02/2005
 10    3      9     11/22/2005
 11    2      15     11/10/2005
 12    5      12     11/19/2005
```

I want to return output as name, comments, sum of all count since 11/10/2005

I am trying the following query(with out date where condition)

```
select 
    Name, Comments, sum(count) 
from 
    Table1 T1 
join 
    Table2 T2 on T1.Id1 = T2.Id1 
group by 
    ID1
```

But it is throwing error

> Name is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the Group by clause.

Can anyone help me with query (with the date where condition)? What's wrong with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `group by Name, Comments`

Comment: Thanks. This worked. can you help me in applying date condition?

Comment: You have to add a `WHERE` to filter by `[date]`, btw **do not** use reserverd words to name object(in your case `date` column) `date` is a datatype.

Comment: Thanks much @Sami. Yeah, that is(date column) just for example

Answer (score 1):

Every column in a select statement without an aggregate function needs to be in the group by sentence too to prevent aggregate errors, about limiting the date, use where clause to define the condition, like shows ahead.

```
select 
    Name, Comments, sum(count) 
from 
    Table1 T1 
join 
    Table2 T2 on T1.Id1 = T2.Id1 
where  
    date >= '2005-11-10 00:00:00'
group by 
    Name, Comments
```

Comment: You should also **explain** what you've changed - and why - don't just dump a pile of code on us!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add any columns not contained in the aggregate function, and use `where` to filter the results:

```
select Name, 
      Comments, 
      sum(count) 
from Table1 T1 join Table2 T2 on T1.Id1 = T2.Id1 
where T2.[date] >= '11/10/2005'
group by Name, Comments
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query

```
SELECT  T1.Name ,
    T1.Comments ,
    SUM(T2.[count]) AS [count]
FROM    Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id1 = T2.Id1
WHERE   CAST(T2.[date] AS DATE) >= CAST('11/10/2005' AS DATE)
GROUP BY T1.Name ,
    T1.Comments
```

Comment: You should also **explain** what you've changed - and why - don't just dump a pile of code on us!